# Simultaneous db4o file access

Tags: visual-studio-2010, db4o

How can I simultaneously access my .db4o database from the Visual Studio's Object Manager Enterprise (OME) db4o plugin and from my application?

I'm starting out with db4o, integrating it with an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a two-layer repository access pattern set up using StructureMap for IoC and I keep getting  DatabaseFileLockedException erros in VS when debugging while using OME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to access a db4o database file from multiple applications at the same time, you need the client-server-mode. So, either your application or a special "db-server only" application has to open the file as server, then both your application and the OME should be able to connect to this server.

The documentation has [an example](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/java/reference/Content/client-server/networked/simple_db4o_server.htm) for this.

I never used OME, so I have no idea how to configure it there.

Comment: Thanks. Is client-server mode required for simultaneous read/write within the same application?

Comment: You have to get the ObjectContainer object to where it is needed - either by creating a new client for an existing server, or by giving the object to where it is needed. You can't simply open the same file again, I think.

Comment: You don't need the full-client-server mode to read/write withing the same application. You can create embedded object-container instances. See here: http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/net35/reference/Content/advanced_topics/session_containers.htm